# Angular Material Dialog change position on window scroll

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular8

I have a Dialog from Materials, and i need him to be always relative to a certain field. I've already accomplished he starts relative at the field, but when i scroll the window down (and I need it to scroll) the dialog comes along and don't reposition, or stay fixed to the initial position

I'm trying to understand if the [scrollstrategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#scroll-strategies) from cdk works with the option reposition, but I cant make it work.

And don't show how it woks

```js
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FilterProspectsComponent, {
            width: '650px',
            // position:{
            //  top: '295px',
            //  left: '180px'
            // },
            autoFocus: false,
            scrollStrategy: this.overlay.scrollStrategies.reposition(),
            data:{}
        });
        let referenceInput = document.querySelector('input.form-filter');
        // dialogRef.updatePosition({ top: `${referenceInput.getBoundingClientRect().top+45}px`, left: `${referenceInput.getBoundingClientRect().left}px` });
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
          console.log('The dialog was closed');
        });
```

I expect the dialog to stay fixed

Answer (score 0):

So, I did it using the `styles.scss` in the app folder, just remove the fixed position in the cdk overlay container

```
.cdk-overlay-container {
   position: unset;
}
```

So, I'm opening a question about the scrollstrategy reposition soon, It's not working or I did'nt understand fully its functionality.